# Smooth regularity of Lindelof smooth manifolds modeled on smoothly regular convenient vector spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The following statement is the first statement of the corollary in Section 27.4 of A. Kriegl, P.W. Michor, The convenient setting of global analysis:

If a (smoothly Hausdorff) smooth manifold is Lindelof and modeled on smoothly regular convenient vector spaces, then it is smoothly paracompact.

The proof only says "See (16.10)". By Theorem 16.10, which states that a Lindelof, smoothly regular space is smoothly paracompact, we have only to show that a smooth manifold as above is smoothly regular. But I cannot prove it.

How can we prove the following assertion?

If a (smoothly Hausdorff) smooth manifold is Lindelof and modeled on smoothly regular convenient vector spaces, then it is smoothly regular.

Comment: They also gave a nonregular example 2nd countable example; 2nd countable implies  Lindelof.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Is the example you mentioned the one in Section 27.6 of their book?

Comment: Yes, the same example.

Comment: From this example, we see the following:

For a Hausdorff smooth manifold $M$, Lindelof property of $M$ and the smooth regularity of the model vector spaces do not imply the smooth regularity of $M$.

What are your thoughts on the first statement of the corollary in Section 27.4? (Of course, if you can show that $X$ in the example is smoothly Hausdorff, then the statement in question is necessarily incorrect.)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word "smooth" in "smoothly regular".